# Ansible error attribute not found due to same variable registration in multiple tasks

Tags: ansible

Below is my playbook that executes only one of the two `raw` modules.

```
   - name: Get Process Dump for tomcat on non-Solaris
     ignore_errors: yes
     block:
       - raw: "ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep; awk -vrc=$? 'BEGIN{print \"rc=\"rc}'"
         register: tomjavadump
         ignore_errors: yes

       - debug:
           msg: "Tomcat DEBUGGG1: tomjavadump:{{ tomjavadump }}"

     when: ansible_distribution != 'Solaris'


   - name: Get Process Dump for tomcat on Solaris
     ignore_errors: yes
     block:
       - raw: "ps auxwww | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep; awk -vrc=$? 'BEGIN{print \"rc=\"rc}'"
         register: tomjavadump
         ignore_errors: yes

       - debug:
           msg: "Tomcat DEBUGGG2: tomjavadump:{{ tomjavadump }}"

     when: ansible_distribution == 'Solaris'


   - debug:
       msg: "Process found"
     when:  tomjavadump.stdout is regex('rc=0')
```

Output with full debug `-vvv`:

```
ansible-playbook -i=all, blocktest.yml -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user1/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 26 2019, 13:23:47) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Parsed all, inventory source with host_list plugin
[WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: all


PLAYBOOK: blocktest.yml ************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in blocktest.yml

PLAY [Play 3- check telnet nodes] **************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/playbook/blocktest.yml:1
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: user1
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 && sleep 0'
ok: [localhost]
META: ran handlers

TASK [raw] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/playbook/blocktest.yml:8
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: user1
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ps -ef | grep tomcat
changed: [localhost] => {
    "changed": true,
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "user1   46691  46690  0 05:15 pts/106  00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ps -ef | grep tomcat\nuser1   46693  46691  0 05:15 pts/106  00:00:00 grep tomcat\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "user1   46691  46690  0 05:15 pts/106  00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ps -ef | grep tomcat",
        "user1   46693  46691  0 05:15 pts/106  00:00:00 grep tomcat"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/playbook/blocktest.yml:10
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "TOMCAT DEBUGGGG1: {'stderr_lines': [], 'stdout': u'user1   46691  46690  0 05:15 pts/106  00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ps -ef | grep tomcat\\nuser1   46693  46691  0 05:15 pts/106  00:00:00 grep tomcat\\n', 'changed': True, 'failed': False, 'stderr': u'', 'rc': 0, 'stdout_lines': [u'user1   46691  46690  0 05:15 pts/106  00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ps -ef | grep tomcat', u'user1   46693  46691  0 05:15 pts/106  00:00:00 grep tomcat']}"
}

TASK [raw] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/playbook/blocktest.yml:19
skipping: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/playbook/blocktest.yml:21
skipping: [localhost] => {}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/playbook/blocktest.yml:26
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/playbook/blocktest.yml': line 26, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - debug:\n     ^ here\n"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Unfortunately, i get "no such Atrribute error" .stdout for the last `debug` task

Can you please suggest how can we take care of such situation so that the the last debug does not fail whether the OS is solaris or non-solaris and we dont have to use a new variable name for `tomjavadump`?

Comment: I can use the variable outside the block as well... the same playbook will work fine if i execute it by removing all the `when` conditions @P....

Comment: I did a small test playbook and the variable definitely prints its values outside the block too !! Kindly suggest.

Comment: can you add your `-vvv` of  raw module execution

Comment: @P.... i updated the original post with complete `-vvv` debug output. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is note from [ansible-doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables):

> If a task fails or is skipped, Ansible still registers a variable with
> a failure or skipped status, unless the task is skipped based on tags.
> See Tags for information on adding and using tags.

When you are skipping the first task it is overwriting it with the values.

Simple example:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: "Running date command expecting 2020 in stdout and storing to var1"
      raw: date
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
      register: var1
      when: True

    - debug: var=var1.stdout

    - name: "Running date command expecting 2020 in stdout and storing to var1"
      raw: date
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
      register: var1
      when: False

    - debug:  var=var1.stdout
    - debug: var=var1
```

In the above example, 2nd debug would produce the same error as reported by you.  However 3rd debug would produce below error, as it can be seen that there is no `stdout` in it.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var1": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

1. The solution is suggested by the ansible doc itself, Use tags or use two different variables.
2. Use Jina2 expression to have only one task for `Solaris` and `non-Solaris` remote. By doing this, you do not have to deal with the skipped or failed variable.

Example:

```
- raw: "{{ 'ps -eaf' if ansible_distribution != 'Solaris' else 'ps auxwww'}} |grep ....bla ...bla...bla"
```

Comment: I get the point @P.... however, how will using the `tags` fall applicable for my very example? I don't know how will tags help for the playbook posted in my original post. Can you suggest please ?

Comment: @Ashar , Try second solution. Rather then having two tasks for each type of `os` , have only one task and leverage the power of `jinja2` expressions.  by doing this you can simply avoid the issue of overwriting of vars.

Comment: Wow ... thank you!!  that seems to be the solution i would pursue... Will test this in the next 24 hours while i accept this as an answer @P....

Comment: @Ashar hope it help,  drop a comment if you need some tweaking.