# Ansible RDS module only works once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, yaml, amazon-rds

I'm using the RDS module in Ansible two times during a play. First time, it records the CNAME. Second time, it waits until the database status is "available".

Problem I'm running into is that it works as expected the first time, but the second time, it fails.

```yaml
---
- name: Wait for RDS to be out of creating state and get its CNAME
  rds:
    command: facts
    instance_name: '{{ wp_db_instance}}'
    region: "{{ region }}"
  register: rds_facts
  until: rds_facts.instance.status != "creating"
  retries: 15
  delay: 30
  become: no

- name: Set Endpoint variable
  set_fact: rds_db_endpoint="{{ (rds_facts.stdout|from_json).DBInstances[0].Endpoint.Address }}"
```

The above code works as expected. It waits for the instance to leave "creating" status and records the name.

Later on in the play, it runs the following.

```yaml
---
- name: Wait for RDS instance to be in available state
  rds:
    command: facts
    instance_name: '{{ wp_db_instance}}'
    region: "{{ region }}"
  register: rds_facts_available
  until: rds_facts_available.instance.status == "available"
  retries: 55
  delay: 30
  become: no
```

This one fails due to "'dict object' has no attribute 'instance'" which tells me the module did not return any facts. Why wouldn't it though? Is there a problem with calling the module twice?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any other task which uses `rds_facts_Available` ?

Comment: @P.... No there isn't.

Comment: the error `"'dict object' has no attribute 'instance'"` is typically seen when the variable is not defined or the task which set it is skipped.

Comment: see this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64326967/6309601

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. It's kind of out there and I'm not sure if this is what fixed it, but here's what I did that works.

The first module (the one that worked) is a part of YAML that's called upon by main.yml.

```yaml
- name: Get RDS endpoint
  include: get_rds_endpoint.yml
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
```

The second module is a part of a different YAML but the files name is a variable:

```yaml
- name: Configure DB
  include: "{{configureDBFile}}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
```

I changed "{{configureDBFile}}" to the name of the actual file and the issue went away.

I am doing regression testing of our old playbooks against the latest release so I have to wonder if an update at some point changed the way environment variables/credentials are passed down?

Answer (score 0):

Change your second tasks as below

```
---
- name: Wait for RDS instance to be in available state
  rds_instance_info:
    db_instance_identifier: '{{ wp_db_instance}}'
    region: "{{ region }}"
  register: rds_facts_available
  until: rds_facts_available.instances[0].db_instance_status == "available"
  retries: 55
  delay: 30
  become: no
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I get the same error with that module. I know the code isn't the issue. It works the first time but for some reason, it is not getting any output from AWS the second time.